# Modifying a point-estimation to get a $unbiased$ $estimator$ $of$ $variance$

Tags: statistics, expected-value, estimation, standard-deviation, parameter-estimation

**My Exercise Problem**:

> Let `x1, x2, ..., x7` be observations of independent random variables `X1, X2, ..., X7` with `E(Xi) = μ` and `Var(Xi) = σ2`, for all `i = 1, 2, ..., 7`.
> Let σ<sup>2</sup><sub>obs</sub> = $c(x_2^2 + x_6^2- \frac{(x_1 + x_7)^2}{2})$ be a point estimation of σ<sup>2</sup>.
> Determine the constant c such that σ<sup>2</sup><sub>obs</sub> becomes a *unbiased estimator of variance*.

**The correct solution:**
c = 1

**What I need help with**
How do I solve this problem? I am very new to point estimations and "unbiased estimators of variance and standard deviations". I want to gradually become better at solving these type of questions, where should I start? Perhaps it would be good for me to start with similar problems but on a easier level, any advice where I can find such problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that $E(X^2)=V(X)+E^2(X)$ and setting

$$T=X_2^2+X_6^2-\frac{(X_1+X_7)^2}{2}$$

You get that

$$E(T)=2(\sigma^2+\mu^2)-\frac{1}{2}(2\sigma^2+4\mu^2)=\dots=\sigma^2$$

Thus T (your original estimator with $c=1$) is unbiased of variance, as requested

Comment: How did you get $$E(T)=2(\sigma^2+\mu^2)-\frac{1}{2}(2\sigma^2+4\mu^2)$$ ? :)

Comment: @AugustJelemson : $$E(T)=E(X_2^2)+E(X_6^2)-\frac{1}{2}E[(X_1+X_7)^2]$$

and so on...by the way did you forget to accept my answer?

Comment: $E(X^2)=V(X)+E^2(X)$
is this a well known theorem/definition that I should know? :) When can I apply this?

Comment: @August Jelemson : like in this case when you have to derive second Moment given variance and mean. In this case any $X_i$ have the same mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$